# Typescript - declare object of type

Tags: typescript, object, types

I have an object defined as:

```
const dict = {
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b",
    "C": "c"
};
```

and a type defined as `type Capital = "A" | "B" | "C";`. 
The type that typescript has automatically assign to `dict` is

```
const dict: {
    A: string,
    B: string,
    C: string,
}
```

Now my question is, is there a way to declare `dict` in a way to use `Capital`? 
Something like `const dict: {Capital: string}`?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `Record<Keys, Type>` type. [More info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

Solution for your case:

```js
type Capital = "A" | "B" | "C";
const dict: Record<Capital, string> = {
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b",
    "C": "c"
};
```

([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghmAlsOAbKBeKAiAgtqAHxwCEDjsZsBuAKAGMB7AOwGdgoATRe4ALigAlCEwBOnADzwkKVABoo7UYmYBzAHyYoAb1pR9OfAOxxscvQexljAIzMX9lbMfrZaAXzpA))